# Unrecognised statement type (near IF)

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to write an SQL query that will update a 'password' record in my database when the user provides a matching email and login. I've written the query below to try and achieve this:

```
SET @password = 'password123';
SET @email = 'email';
SET @newPassword = 'pass54321';


IF `customer.Password` = @password WHERE `customer.Email` == @email
BEGIN
set `customer`.`Password` = @newPassword
END
```

I get an error saying 'Unrecognised statement type (near IF)'. If anyone knows how to solve this, any help would be appreciated! I'm very new to using SQL so this might be completely wrong!!!

Comment: In MySQL, `IF` is only allowed in programming blocks -- stored procedures, functions, and triggers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a mysql user but looking at the docs (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/), there are a couple of routes to take. I'm showing you the upsert way (which is pretty cool, I've never seen it before).

First, you should be using primary keys to help with lookup performance and to help qualify the selection criteria.

```
  # sample table with primary key
  CREATE TABLE customer (customer_id int not null primary key, name VARCHAR(20), email VARCHAR(20), password VARCHAR(20));

  # seed with data
  INSERT INTO customer VALUES(1,'John','john@email.com','password1');
  INSERT INTO customer VALUES(2,'Jane','jane@email.com','passwordx');

  # set test params
  SET @password = 'password1';
  SET @email = 'john@email.com';
  SET @newPassword = 'pass54321';

  /*
     depending on how the rest of the query is structured or if this
      doesn't fit the requirements...you have the option to use IF EXISTS

    This is using the 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' to check if the record exists then performs an update if it does or an insert if it doesn't (aka upsert)

  */
  INSERT INTO customer VALUES (1, 'John', 'john@email.com', 'password1')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE password = @newPassword;


  # test for password update
  SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customer_id = 1
```

If your table doesn't have primary keys, run! It may make more sense to use the `If EXISTS` statement.

Tag someone in your organization to verify that what you're doing is within the coding standards. Use the MySql docs site - it seems like it's well maintained.